# Is possible put in a communication 2 fork() in C++?

Tags: c++, fork

I want to do a server that have 2 fork.
Is possible that one can communicate with the other one, for example to stop it?

Thank you.

Comment: The phrase you seem to be looking for is *"inter-process communication"* and the tag on Stack Overflow is [tag:ipc].

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to do so, and quite common. One of the usual and simple ways of doing this is to use pipes.

See this article for an example: [Creating Pipes in C](http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html).

Answer (score 0):

if you use word 'fork' I assume that you have server written on UNIX-like operation system.
In this case you have Inter Process Communication (IPC) mechanism to communicate two different processes. See wiki (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).
On windows like machines you can use another mechanism (also called IPC), but a little different implemented).